# How to find $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{ \int_x^1 \arctan(t^2)\, dt}{x} $

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

Any tips on how to find this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{
\displaystyle\int_x^1 \arctan(t^2)\, dt}{x}
$$

Comment: Hospital? ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

Let $L$ be given by the limit

$$L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_x^1 \arctan(t^2)dt$$

Note that the limit is in the form for [L'Hospital's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html).  Thus, we have

$$L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_x^1 \arctan(t^2)dt=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(- \arctan(x^2)\right)=-\pi/2$$

Comment: And hence $-\pi/2 > 0$. Hmm. (_Your_ $L$ is $\pi/2$, hence the answer to _his_ question is $-\pi/2$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've fixed the limits.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on L'Hospital and how you use it,thanks

Comment: Yabbut now my comment makes no sense. Heh. Never mind...

Comment: @Zahir Say $F(x)=\int_1^x f(t)\,dt$. The Fundamental theorem of calculus says (under some hypotheses) that $F'=f$.

Comment: @zahir I've provided a link for L'Hospital's Rule.   I hope that this helps.

Comment: yeah but where did 1,x go :D? and where did this - came from

Comment: @zahir I've provided a link for L'Hospital's Rule.   I hope that this helps.  Note that in particular, all one needs here is that the denominator $G(x)=x \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$.  Then,  for $F(x) =\int_x^1 \arctan(t^2)dt$, we have $\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)/G(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}F'(x)/G'(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}(-arctan(x^2)/1)=-\pi/2$.  The minus sign appears because $x$ is in the lower limit.  Please let me know if this helps

Comment: so the derivative of $arctan(t^2) is -arctan(x^2)$

Comment: @Zahir The derivative of $F(x)=\int_x^1 \arctan(t^2)dt$ with respect to $x$ is $-\arctan(x^2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really mean $\int_x^1$? Seems a little curious, $\int_1^x$ would make more sense, given that $x$ is tending to infinity.

Yes, you could get this from L'Hopital as suggested. Imo using L'Hopital is very often a bad thing, because one doesn't learn anything. A simple direct proof is better here because it works in cases where the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus doesn't quite apply, it allows you to prove similar things for series, where L'Hopital makes no sense, etc. So:

Theorem. If $f$ is continuous on $[1,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ then $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x\int_1^xf(t)\,dt=L.$$ Just like a well known result for series.

Lemma. Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $|L-f(t)|<\epsilon$ everywhere on $[a,b]$. Then $|L-\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bf(t)\,dt|<\epsilon$.

Proof $$\left|L-\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bf\right|
=\left|\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b(L-f)\right|
\le\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b|L-f|
<\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b\epsilon=\epsilon.$$

Proof of the theorem: Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $A>1$ so $|L-f(t)|<\epsilon$ for all $t\ge A$. Suppose $x>A$. Then $$L-\frac1x\int_1^xf(t)\,dt
=-\frac1x\int_1^Af(t)\,dt+\frac AxL+\frac{x-A}x\left(L-\frac1{x-A}\int_A^xf(t)\,dt\right)=I+II+III.$$It's clear that $I$ and $II$ tend to $0$ as $x\to\infty$, and the lemma shows that $|III|<\epsilon$ for all $x>A$. So the whole thing is less than $3\epsilon$ if $x$ is large enough.

Comment: I will add a few links: [Prove $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf(t)dt=a$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257193/prove-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac1x-int-0xftdt-a), [Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(x) \ dx = \gamma$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772807/show-that-lim-x-to-infty-frac1x-int-0x-fx-dx-gamma)  and [$f(x)$ monotonic integrable function and $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=a$, Prove: $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=a$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87816)